# Jmeter CSV issue

Tags: csv, jmeter

Please help me with following issue:
I have a simple Jmeter test with where variables are stored in CSV file. There is only one request in the test:

Get .../api/${page} , where ${page} is a variable from CSV

Everything goes well with thread properties for ex. 10 threads x30 loop count

If i increase any parameter, for ex. in 10x40 or 15x30, i receive at least one error and looks like this is jmeter issue:
one request (random) isn't able to take variable from CSV and i got an error:

- -.../api/page returns 404 error

So the question is - is there any limit in jmeter's connection to CSV file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no limit, but make sure there is no blank line at the end of the csv file, and did you check Recycle on EOF?

Answer (score 0):

A key point to focus on is the way your application manage the case when 2 different users require the same page.
There are few checks that I would recommend:

1. be sure that the "Recycle on EOF" property is true
2. be sure that you have more lines on CSV than the number of threads you are firing
3. use a "View result tree" controller to investigate the kind of error you are getting

Let us know

Comment: why 2. if recycle on EOF?

Comment: In theory, it is not needed. Practically I try to avoid such a situation.

Comment: Use 3. to see what data is actually used to forge the request.